# CSS elements are not showing up as nodes through rvest

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract reviews from a [Bed Bath and Beyond page](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/zigami-rod-pocket-back-tab-window-curtain-panel/3256914) using [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf). The reviews section is in a separate tab, accessed by appending `#prodExplore-tabs2` to the URL, which I have done. The nodes I need are accessed within the `span` of class `BVRRReviewText`.

Here is what I have:

```
page<-read_html("http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/zigami-rod-pocket-back-tab-window-curtain-panel/3256914#prodExplore-tabs2")
node<-html_nodes(page,".BVRRReviewText")
```

My node reads

> {xml_nodeset (0)}

I've tried both xpath and css methods, but none seem to be finding the nodes I need within the reviews drawer.

Comment: Are you sure the data is in the html source and not added by JavaScript after page load? Make sure to look at the raw html response from the server. What you see in a browser isn't the same as what http sees necessarily. You may need to use something like R Selenium to execute the JavaScript.

Comment: It's definitely dynamically created. RSelenium is your best bet.

Comment: you're both right. Thanks!